# how to require a class in node.js

Tags: node.js

my code that works..

```
var express=require("express"),
app=express();

class bar {
   constructor()
   {
     this.user_name=null;
     this.user_surname=null;
     this.user_age=null;
   }

   name(user_name) {
     this.user_name=user_name;
     return this;
   }

   surname(user_surname) {
     this.user_surname=user_surname;
     return this;
   }

   age(user_age) {
     this.user_age=user_age;
     return this;
   }

   get(callback) {

     var list ={};

     list.uname=this.user_name;
     list.usurname=this.user_surname;
     list.uage=this.user_age;

     callback(list);
   }

}



app.get("/liste/:ext",function(req,res){

  var ext=req.params.ext;

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  if(ext==1)
  {
    var newbar=new bar();
    newbar.name("alex").surname("broox").age(32).get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })

  }

  if(ext==2)
  {
    var newbar=new bar();
    newbar.name("alex2").get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })
  }

})

app.listen(4000,function(log){
  console.log("listening")
})
```

but..following code does not work.. with require that class from other file..

test.js

```
module.exports = {

class bar {
   constructor()
   {
     this.user_name=null;
     this.user_surname=null;
     this.user_age=null;
   }

   name(user_name) {
     this.user_name=user_name;
     return this;
   }

   surname(user_surname) {
     this.user_surname=user_surname;
     return this;
   }

   age(user_age) {
     this.user_age=user_age;
     return this;
   }

   get(callback) {

     var list ={};

     list.uname=this.user_name;
     list.usurname=this.user_surname;
     list.uage=this.user_age;

     callback(list);
   }

}

};
```

app.js file.. with require that class

```
var express=require("express"),
app=express();


require("./test")



app.get("/liste/:ext",function(req,res){

  var ext=req.params.ext;

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  if(ext==1)
  {
    var newbar=new bar();
    newbar.name("alex").surname("broox").age(32).get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })

  }

  if(ext==2)
  {
    newbar.name("alex2").get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })
  }

})

app.listen(4000,function(log){
  console.log("listening")
})
```

but why does not it work...please help me..above code that works but this code that does not work..

Answer (score 31):

When exporting classes in node you need to define the class first, then export the class using `module.exports` followed by the name of the class you wish to export.

```
// test.js
class Bar {
       constructor() {
         this.user_name=null;
         this.user_surname=null;
         this.user_age=null;
       }

       name(user_name) {
         this.user_name=user_name;
         return this;
       }

       surname(user_surname) {
         this.user_surname=user_surname;
         return this;
       }

       age(user_age) {
         this.user_age=user_age;
         return this;
       }

       get(callback) {

         var list ={};

         list.uname=this.user_name;
         list.usurname=this.user_surname;
         list.uage=this.user_age;

         callback(list);
       }
}

module.exports = Bar
```

From there you can just `require` the file and grab the class as such.

```
var Bar = require('./test');
var bar = new Bar();
```

Answer (score 4):

`test.js` isn't valid syntax - you shouldn't have your entire file wrapped in braces like that. `module.exports` is just a variable which you set; if you want to export `bar`, set it to `bar`:

```
class bar {
   ...
}

module.exports = bar;
```

Additionally, you need to assign the result of your `require` call in `app.js`.

```
var bar = require("./test");
```

(On a slightly pedantic note - it's more idiomatic to captialize your class names!)

Answer (score 0):

hello again @DominicValenciana

test.js

```
class bar {
   constructor()
   {
     this.user_name=null;
     this.user_surname=null;
     this.user_age=null;
   }

   name(user_name) {
     this.user_name=user_name;
     return this;
   }

   surname(user_surname) {
     this.user_surname=user_surname;
     return this;
   }

   age(user_age) {
     this.user_age=user_age;
     return this;
   }

   get(callback) {

     var list ={};

     list.uname=this.user_name;
     list.usurname=this.user_surname;
     list.uage=this.user_age;

     callback(list);
   }

}

module.exports = bar;
```

app.js

```
var express=require("express"),
app=express();


app.get("/liste/:ext",function(req,res){

  var ext=req.params.ext;

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  if(ext==1)
  {
    var bar=new require('./test');
    bar.name("alex").surname("broox").age(32).get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })

  }

  if(ext==2)
  {
    var bar=new require('./test');
    bar.name("alex2").get(function(result){
      res.json({data:result})
    })
  }

})

app.listen(4000,function(log){
  console.log("listening")
})
```

as error :  TypeError: bar.name is not a function

Comment: So let's try something real quick then.
`var bar = new require('./test')();`

Comment: Also make sure that `app.js` and `test.js` are in the same directory.

Comment: ı tried it too..var bar=new require('./test')();  error so : TypeError: Class constructor bar cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: Then let's do this
`var Bar = require('./test');
var bar = new Bar();`

Comment: Let me know what works so I can update my answer appropriately.

Comment: Excellent I have updated my answer so that it reflects the working version of your code. Thanks for working with me!

Comment: I can't give reputation for that my point is low..Sorry for this about

Comment: At your current reputation you are incapable of up voting however you should still be able to award the answer to whom ever you believe best answered your question by clicking the check mark under the `upvote` and `downvote` buttons. (Just an FYI, please give the answer to whom you see fit, do not feel like you have to give it to me.)

Comment: What I'm talking about is actually different. On Stack over flow upvoting makes the answer rise to the top of answers provided for visibility and reputation purposes. However there is another feature when you are the person asking the question. You are capable of choosing the answer to the question, even if it doesn't have the most up votes. There is a green check mark visible to the question asker bellow each `upvote` and `downvote`. I'm still kinda new to stack my self so I thought you may want to know.